# Can't find images associated with Mozilla Ghostwriter demo

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, firefox-developer-tools

I have kind of a weird question. I want to get the following demo up and running, then modify it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/ghostwriter-art-studio/launch

However, the source code is apparently outdated. So I went back to the demo itself and used the "save as" command to save the files to my computer. However, no images are downloaded.

I can copy the images form the source download page - but they don't include eraser.png or eraser_shadow.png. So I checked the demo's CSS file. The path looks very simple...yet I can't find the image.

So that's my immediate question - where can I find the images eraser.png and eraser_shadow.png.

I searched the Demo page for support/contact information, but haven't yet figured out how Mozilla/GitHub work. It looks to me like this project may have been abandoned.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. The problem is the Ghostwriter script disables your cursor, more or less turning it into a writing tool. So when I right-click on an image, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project appears to be open-source with all the other images available. I'm assuming the author just forgot to include these 2 remaining images when he created the repository.

You can pull the images using the F12 developer tools:

https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/h/u/hunterloftis/1bb05943a07a6f68146f869ae2bb6b39/ghostwriter-art-stud_1305739973_demo_package/css/images/eraser.png

https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/h/u/hunterloftis/1bb05943a07a6f68146f869ae2bb6b39/ghostwriter-art-stud_1305739973_demo_package/css/images/shadow_eraser.png